# query in codeigniter, querybuilder and "classical"

Tags: php, sql, database, codeigniter

i'm building a web app for a project which is required to have a join (teacher's specs). So, I have this problem: I have no sql knowledge. I'm trying to create it but unsuccessfully. In the picture you can find my database structure. [image: database]users.username are unique and they are the same in requests.applicant... So, i need to retrieve the list of vehicle_id in the table requests for a given username.

So, in my controller i have this:

```
 $data['your_vehicles'] = $this->vehicle_model->get_your_vehicles($_SESSION['username']);
```

so i give to my model the username of the logged user. The method is the following:

```
 public function get_your_vehicles($username){

 $this->db->select('users.*, requests.*');
 $this->db->from('users');
 $this->db->join('requests', 'requests.applicant = users.username', 'inner');
 $query=$this->db->get();
 return $query ->result();

 //return $query->result_array();

 }
```

first of all I can't pass the $username variable into the query and this is a problem... Can you help me building the query please?

Comment: Just a few tips for your SQL knowledge: instead of using the `username` as the foreign key (the key to identify which user put it which request) you can use the `id`, since it will also be unique and probably faster (exactly like you used the `vehicle_id`). This also means you could loose the `applicant_email`, which you can retrieve from the user via said `id`. The key in vehicles (`id_vehicle`) could also be named `id` (so all your primary keys will always be easy to spot!) The rest looks pretty neat for someone with no SQL knowledge ;)

Comment: Just an extra comment with a tip; name foreign keys `singular tablename` + `_id`. So if you want to connect your user to the request, create a `user_id` field in the requests table. This is a nice way to easily see what is going on by just a quick glance at the database schema.

Answer (score 1):

What information is saved $ _SESSION ['username']?

```
 $data['your_vehicles'] = $this->vehicle_model->get_your_vehicles($_SESSION['username']);
```

but if $ _SESSION ['username'] gets the user this would be your solution.

```
public function get_your_vehicles($username){

    $this->db->select('users.*, requests.*');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->join('requests', 'requests.applicant = users.username', 'inner');
    $this->db->where('users.username',$username);
    $query=$this->db->get();
    return $query ->result();

    // $query ->result() ==> Array Objects
    // $query->result_array() ==> Array Arrays

}
```

and if you want to obtain the vehicle data in the query

```
public function get_your_vehicles($username){

    $this->db->select('users.*, requests.*,vehicles.*');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->join('requests', 'requests.applicant = users.username', 'inner');
    $this->db->join('vehicles', 'vehicles.id_vehicle = requests.vehicle_id', 'inner');
    $this->db->where('users.username',$username);
    $query=$this->db->get();
    return $query ->result();

    // $query ->result() ==> Array Objects
    // $query->result_array() ==> Array Array
}
```